# Android ProGuard Optimization

Tags: android, optimization, proguard

To perform optimization on my Android app I enabled the following statement in `project.properties`.

```
target=android-15
android.library=true
proguard.config=proguard-android-optimize.txt
```

and in the proguard-android-optimize.txt, I have written the `-dontwarn` and `-keep` statements.

My build is getting successful but it is not getting optimized: my problem is that The size of the APK is remaining the same.

Can anyone suggest me how can I optimize my code?

Answer (score 0):

The line in `project.properties` that enables ProGuard with optimization typically looks like this:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

You can of course replace these two files by a single custom configuration file, but you then should be careful to specify the proper settings. If you specify `-dontshrink`, `-dontoptimize`, `-dontobfuscate`, or `-keep` with patterns that are too broad, you may not see the optimizations that you'd like.

With Ant and Eclipse, ProGuard is only applied for release builds.

With Gradle, you have to enable ProGuard in `build.gradle`.